# Error during insert of record from asp.net into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

[I got this error during insert of data into a SQL Server database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBg4X.jpg)

Here is my code in button click event

```
try
{
    string ConnString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\\MOD03-PC\\Share Folder mod03\\amts\\amtsfuelconsuption\\AmtsFuelConsumption\\AmtsFuelConsumption\\App_Data\\AmtsDatabse.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=900,providerName=System.Data.SqlClient";  
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@ConnString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertBodyTypeMaster", con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bodytypename", txtBTname.Text.ToString());

    con.Open();

    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (k != 0)
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "Record Inserted Succesfully into the Database";
        lblmessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;
    }

    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblmessage.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: defination is below...                                                                        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBodyTypeMaster]
 (@bodytypename varchar(50)) 
AS
 INSERT INTO BodyTypeMaster values(@bodytypename); 
RETURN 0

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things wrong;

- As mentioned, you need to change your `Connect Timeout=900,` to `Connect Timeout=900;`
- You need to delete `providerName=System.Data.SqlClient` part since you *already* using the .NET provider for SQL Server. Provider names for .NET are implicit based on the implementing class and *not needed* to specified in the connection string. When you delete this, you will not need `;` at the end of `Connect Timeout=900;` anymore
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.
- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Final connection string should be as;

```
string ConnString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0,AttachDbFilename=\\MOD03-PC\\Share Folder mod03\\amts\\amtsfuelconsuption\\AmtsFuelConsumption\\AmtsFuelConsumption\\App_Data\\AmtsDatabse.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=900";
```

Comment: Couple of tips, store configuration in a config file, also, close your connection as soon as posible, open it as late as possible.

Comment: @Ernesto Exactly. Since OP opens it just before executing, that's fine. `using` statement handles the closing/disposing part as well.

Comment: Agree, the using block is a must, im talking more of, don't do a lot of things while the connection is still open like updating your UI (is not an issue probably in this case) or processing your data, save the result for later if you need to, but let the connection close as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma and not a semi-colon after the 900 in the connect timeout property in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Cause your connection string is total weird. remove those `;` and replace them with `,`. Also, make sure you spell them properly. It should be like

```
string ConnString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0,AttachDbFilename=\\MOD03-PC\\Share Folder mod03\\amts\\amtsfuelconsuption\\AmtsFuelConsumption\\AmtsFuelConsumption\\App_Data\\AmtsDatabse.mdf,Integrated Security=True,Connect Timeout=900;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient";
```

Also the below line

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@ConnString);
```

It should be

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
```

You are calling `Dispose()` inside `try` block which is big blunder as shown below. Either use `Using(...)` block (or) `finally` block

```
try
{
 ....
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Should be

```
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Looks like it's time you should start reading through documentation.